# Quasi-algebraically closed field

Tags: nt.number-theory, class-field-theory

Is there a field that is $C_{3/2}$ but not $C_1$?

Comment: The notation is explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-algebraically_closed_field

Comment: Do you mean it the other way around, that is $C_1$ but not $C_{1.5}$? We have $C_s \Rightarrow C_t$ for $s > t$. Anyway, the question is interesting, and I haven't seen condition $C_r$ considered anywhere for $r \notin \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. (For easy reference to others, it means the non-trivial solvability over the field of any system of homogeneous polynomial equations in $n$ variables and degrees $d_i$ satisfying $\sum_i d_i^r < n$. Examples include all $r$-dimensional function fields over an algebraically closed field.)

Comment: Bjorn Poonen used to ask questions similar to this when he was working on model theory and arithmetic.  I think there is some feeling that the model-theoretic constructions might give fields that are $C_t$ but not $C_s$ -- just adjoin a root of every appropriate polynomial.

Comment: @Vesselin: I think the OP has it the right way around: indeed the $C_r$ condition gets weaker as $r$ increases.  For instance $\mathbb{F}_q((t))$ is $C_2$ but not $C_1$.  Anyway, I am pretty sure this is an open problem.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: You are right, my mistake. Thanks for correcting me, and apologies to the OP for the oversight.